# How can I pass on an array of data from the model to the controller and then back to the model?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to select rows from my DB table based on information I get from the other rows(previous query). The trouble I'm having is converting the `$query->result_array();` in the controller to use it in the model again and subsequently the view.

I've tried to do a `foreach` loop and returning the `$query->result_array();` from the model, this turned out to be problematic as it didn't fit the different stages I have on my website(I have several stages of content).

> controller.php

```
public function firststage() {

   $this->load->model('Model');
   $get_stage = $_GET["stg"];

   $get_results = $this->Model->get_stage_id($get_stage);
   foreach ($get_results as $results) {

   $id = $results["id"];
   }

   $data['result'] = $this->Model->stage_results($get_stage, $id);
   $this->load->view('stage_view', $data);
}
```

> model.php

```
public function get_stage_id($get_stage) {

   $this->db->where('stage_parent', $get_stage);
   $query = $this->db->get('stages');

   return $query->result_array();
}

public function stage_results($get_stage, $id) {

   $this->db->where('stage_id', $get_stage);
   $this->db->where('stage_id', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get('stage_contents');

   foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {

   $rows[] = array(
   'id' => $row["id"],
   'name' => $row["name"]
   ); 

  }
  return $rows;
}
```

Expected the output selection to be based on the first query result, instead I get the `Undefined variable: rows` when I run all of it. I don't think my view is relevant to this question, but please let me know if you think otherwise!

Comment: I don't understand the problem but `$this->db->where('stage_id', $get_stage);
   $this->db->where('stage_id', $id);` means that  stage_id should be equal to two different values in one time

Comment: Exactly, but the output I get is what I don't understand!

Comment: Can you show some table data with schema?

Comment: @frogman578 Check line of the error

Comment: @splash58 line of error is `return $rows;`

Comment: It means $query->result_array() return empty result. and you don't define rows

Comment: And that empty array is the result of incorrect two where conditions

Comment: Put $rows = array() in beginning of stage_results()

Comment: That doesn't make sense though, I double checked and the names match.

Comment: @AnkurMishra but then I would have more errors since I have to run the query before assigning the associative array

Comment: If you don't change the where clause you can avoid errors just write with the same result  :) `public function stage_results($get_stage, $id) { return []; }`

Comment: @splash58 I don't really understand, do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @frogman578 Show me table structure and data pls

Comment: @AnkurMishra which table?

Comment: stage_contents and stages table

Comment: stages: `id`   `parent`   `name`;    stage_contents: `id`   `name`   `stage_id`;   What I want to do is get rows from `stage_contents` where `stage_id` matches both `stages` `id` but also where `stage_id` matches `stages` `id` where `parent` matches the original `id`(from `$_GET` method)

Comment: @frogman578 please change the function stage_results like this:

Comment: public function stage_results($get_stage, $id) {
   $rows = [];
   $this->db->where('stage_id', $get_stage);
   $this->db->or_where('stage_id', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get('stage_contents');

   foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $rows[] = array(
    'id' => $row["id"],
    'name' => $row["name"]
    );
  }
  return $rows;
}

Comment: And tell me its working or not?

Answer (score 2):

you get the error

> Undefined variable: $rows

because your query doesn't return any result, therefore $rows is not defined

you can resolve this checking if there are rows returned:

```
if($query->num_rows()){
   foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
       $rows[] = array(
           'id' => $row["ID"],
           'name' => $row["name"]
        ); 
   }
}else {$rows='no records found';}
print_r($rows);die;
```

this prints either the array (if there are results), or 'no records'

or simply do:

```
$rows = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
   $rows[] = array(
       'id' => $row["ID"],
       'name' => $row["name"]
    ); 
}
```

then you get an empty array if there are no results

Comment: I think its enough to define rows as an empty array before loop. But it it will not return a non-empty result till change logic

Comment: @splash58 yes sure, I wanted to show that the query doesn't return anything

Comment: Yea it does show me one record I select with matching parents, though for some reason it doesn't show others.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, since both arrays loop out the same, I also checked the DB and it contains valid info corresponding to the first one which showed.

Comment: your where clause is not making sense, if $id is equal to $get_stage, you don't need the 2nd where(), if they are different, you never get a result, except you change the logic to an OR clause (or_where())

Comment: nah `$id` is based of of `$get_stage`, I want to get results matching both values